# Verify emails using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a list of email addresses in Google spreadsheet, I need to send them the same mail. so I wrote a script using Google Script that goes over the emails and send it.

My problem is that I am not sure that all the email addresses are valid. for example, name@gmaial.com instead of name@gmail.com. In this case, the mail won't be delivered.

I used Hunter API to achieve this, but I have a limited number of calls to theses API.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you consider to be valid and invalid? name@gmaial.com is a perfectly valid email address as far as format is concerned. Are you trying to whitelist major email providers?

Comment: Yes, I don’t mean to check the format. What I need is to check if the email exist and reachable.

Comment: There's no way to know for sure whether an email address is reachable, at least ahead of time. If I owned gmaial.com, for example, I could set up a mail server and an account using that email address. Why exactly do you need to know if the email address is real in the first place? Depending on your needs you could either send a verification link by email that needs to be clicked before something happens or you could whitelist major email providers like Gmail, Yahoo, etc. But without knowing your exact problem it's hard to recommend something.